# How to build an event listener and an if statements with an OR operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since I don't want to write my function twice, I want to execute some code if either `.customer` is clicked OR the string 'customer' is a part of the url.

Somehow like this:

```
$('.customer').click(function() {
```

OR

```
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#customer') > -1 ) {
```

What's a nice way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `$('.customer').click(function() {` isn't an if statement, it's an event listener / handler. It will listen for click events on that element triggering the function attached....

Comment: Much better! You have two great answers below so I won't bother submitting anything as it will only be the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to abstract the logic that would be performed into a new function and then just call that function in either case. This has the benefit of readability and an easy ability for future expansion (if you wanted to add another case that certain code should be executed).

The code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function logicToBeExecuted()
    {
        // Logic goes in here
    }

    if (document.location.href.indexOf('#customer') > -1 ) {
        logicToBeExecuted();
    }

    $('.customer').click(function()
    {
        logicToBeExecuted();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought there would be a way to work with an `OR` operator but this also does it.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap all your code that will be executed into a function and just call that function for every listener

```
$('.customer').click(function() { 
     myFunction(); 
});

if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#customer') > -1 ) {
     myFunction(); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, that would also make it happen.